# mongo db can't start ubuntu 15.10

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-15.10

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked.

What should I do? help me..

> ~$ mongo MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3 connecting to: test
>   2016-02-26T17:40:18.552+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused 2016-02-26T17:40:18.552+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't
>   connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:224:14 @(connect):1:6
>
> exception: connect failed

Comment: did you even search for this? Seems to be answered on ask-ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/617097/mongodb-2-6-does-not-start-on-ubuntu-15-04

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `sudo service mongod start` - please note the lack of b in `mongod`

Comment: I tried it but failed
$ sudo service mongod start
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --journal
```

Different terminal is opening and `mongo` command is starting with